# Mule flow request-response issue

Tags: mule

In this flow the HTTP inbound is configured with request-response. But I still dont get the response as it is routed to the File outbound. How do I get a response for the HTTP endpoint and also route the response to File outbound.

```
<flow name="helloFlow1" doc:name="helloFlow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="9095" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <custom-transformer class="com.uk.MyTransformer" doc:name="Java"/>
    <component class="com.uk.MyComponent" doc:name="Java"/>
    <echo-component doc:name="Echo"/>
    <file:outbound-endpoint path="C:\" outputPattern="file#[function:datestamp]" doc:name="File"/>
```

Comment: If used for logging, prefer the <logger /> message processor instead of the <echo-component />.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't receive a response because nothing creates one: the file:outbound-endpoint is one-way per nature and doesn't generate a response event.

Assuming you want the same content written to the file to be also returned to the caller of the HTTP endpoint, one option consists in "detaching" the writing to the file in a parallel async flow so the main flow returns its current value to the caller:

```
<flow name="helloFlow1" doc:name="helloFlow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="9095" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <custom-transformer class="com.uk.MyTransformer" doc:name="Java"/>
    <component class="com.uk.MyComponent" doc:name="Java"/>
    <echo-component doc:name="Echo"/>
    <async>
        <file:outbound-endpoint path="C:\" outputPattern="file#[function:datestamp]" doc:name="File"/>
    </async>
</flow>
```

Comment: As per this example Iam supposed to receive a response for the inbound service in Browser/SoapUI and also the same response needs to be routed to the outbound File endpoint. But why I did not get the response for the inbound HTTP endpoint? http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3EXAMPLES/Using+Outbound+Endpoints+to+Publish+Data

Comment: The last element in your flow is an in-only outbound endpoint thus "the buck stops here", ie there's no more message to route back to the caller after this endpoint has been called. So you want the result of the component call to be both written to file and returned to the caller? Is that it?

Comment: Assuming your answer is yes, I've modified my response already.

Comment: Thanks a lot this is the solution I wanted.